# Counting values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I'm trying to count all the values inside an array, I've tried using count() but to no avail, the array values may also have negatives in them, example:

```
Array
(
    [name] => 1
    [phone] => 1
    [emailX] => 1
    [car] => 0
    [finance] => 2
    [employed] => 1
    [credit] => -5
)
```

If you count all of them together, the result should be 1, I'm just not sure how to go about it.. :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [array_sum()](http://php.net/array_sum):

```
$sum = array_sum($myArray);
```

The [count()](http://php.net/count) function gives you the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 3):

count will return the number of elements, you will want to use array_sum

```
$sum = array_sum($arr);
```